# What does the condition "new pull" mean?

Tags: hard-drive, terminology

I'm looking for a hard drive, and some of the conditions are listed as "New Pull" or "System Pull". I figure the System Pull means "taken from a computer and now sold separately" but what does New Pull mean? Does this mean it was assembled and never used? Or maybe it has been freshly pulled from a used machine?

Comment: I've also seen the phrase "working pull" a lot recently. Basically that means the same as the others: that a piece of hardware that was functioning correctly was taken out of a system. Usually it was taken out either because it was upgraded (and now the person wants to sell the old one to recoup some of the cost of the upgrade), or because the system died and they didn't want the components that still work to go to waste.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

System pull means it has been taken out of a previously used system, but was tested and working. New pull means it was taken out of a system that was never used.

Comment: More info: http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/getpartsonline/conditions.html

Answer (score 8):

For anyone trying to figure out what the terms *new pull* and *new bulk* mean in terms of disk drives (and other computer components), please see this link: http://www.istoragenetworks.com/avoid-bulk.php

Disk drive manufacturers (and system builders such as HP, IBM, SUN/Oracle) do not sell equipment as *bulk*. “Bulk pack” and “ new pull” merchandise are either factory rejected units or plain old used units that ended up in the hands of a broker that does not have the tools to properly test the equipment.

"Gnoupi" hit the nail right on when he said "new pull" is "shiesty term created by the industry." How often do you think users buy servers / workstations / SANs ,yank out all the components without using them, and post them for sale?

Users should use tools like Seagate SeaTools(http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/) to read the number of power on hours on any drive they purchase that is not factory sealed. Shamefully, we have found that just about every disk drive we have purchased (advertised as a new pull or new bulk) had thousands of power on hours recorded in the log pages.

Just about all U320 and U160 SCSI drives are out of production as of 2012. Production on the Seagate Cheetah 15K.5 U320 line of drives ended in December of 2011. Production of the Cheetah 10K.7 line of drives ended in 2007.

(Side note: I work for iStorage Networks, and the majority of products we sell are end of life disk drives.)

Answer (score 3):

"New pull means it was taken out of a system that was never used."

That statement is not true.  It was taken out of a system for what ever reason,
upgrade perhaps, but shows no signs of problems.  It has been used, but no problems
has been detected after a thorough check.

---

It's a shiesty term created by the industry.

For people looking for new and have new in their heads
when new isn't available and never will be.

New Pull is a drive that is pulled from a system, that is clean and can pass for new with no failures at all. In football terms, a reliable veteran.

Comment: remember you can use smartd tools to check the spin time of a drive, to give you an idea of how much usage the drive has seen. This may be helpful if buying used drives.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the fine print for sites where you can actually find a definition of terms, you will see that "New Pull" means used.  It *might* be from a system that was never used.  But it also might be a used component that is "like new".

Here is the definition from one site:

New Pull products are used more than 1 year have some scratches but are working like new.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame how some people use their own definitions based on their experience rather then the standard industry definition:

New Pull means it was an item that has been pulled or torn down from a machine that never been used (whether it was a printer/pc/server ...etc).

Pull can be either new or refurbished (used). If the machine had been used, then the pull item will be used. If the machine was not used, then the item pulled out is a new pull.

In most cases, it is better and cheaper to tear-down a new machine and sell it in parts, as it is cheaper than buying new retail. The suppliers make more money this way which allows them to still be very competitive.